# Como integro o conecto un aplicativo web a shopify

Tags: api, conexión, shopify, integración-continua

Hola  buen dia querida comunidad , quisiera pedirles su gran ayuda, me encuentro en un dilema ya que mi empresa tiene varios sitios ecommerce en shopify y me pidieron que integrara los sitios a un servicio que nos presta una empresa trasnportadora , mi pregunta es como puedo vincular directamente  el aplicativo con nuestro sitio en shopify , si no se puede directamemte que apis puedo utilizar?

he intentado con zapier y zoho y no se como empezar

Comment: espero me ayuden querida comunidad